# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running

Tags: server

I have Ubuntu 16.04 running and Nvidia drivers and CUDA and cud installed a long time ago. Yesterday the server was rebooted, and after I login through ssh, I wanted to check the GPU using `nvidia-smi` but failed. 
The error message was "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."

The server has:

Ubuntu 16.04

Nvidia k80c x4

CUDA 9.0

Has anyone faced this problem and can offer a possible solution? I don't really want to reinstall the driver as it could cause other problems.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is eventually solved by re-installing the Nvidia GPU driver. The root cause of this error is because the server has shut down due to unstable power supply while running using the GPU.